# How did Scott Horowitz "hoist" the Mars Society's flag up STS-105's "mast"?

Tags: space-shuttle, space-art

The medium.com's [Retired NASA Astronaut Joins Crew That’s Building 21st Century Transportation Network](https://medium.com/davnetwork/retired-nasa-astronaut-joins-crew-thats-building-21st-century-transportation-network-6bc54a2d20a4) says:

> At NASA, ([Scott J. Horowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_J._Horowitz#Post_NASA)) was responsible for selecting SpaceX — the company run by Elon Musk when he isn’t busy building the industry’s most thrilling quasi-autonomous electric vehicles — as contractors to develop Dragon. That was the world’s first commercial spacecraft to deliver cargo to the International Space Station. Like Musk, our new advisor Horowitz is a leading advocate of establishing permanent human outposts on Mars. **On his 2001 space shuttle flight, when he served as commander, he ordered the Mars Society’s flag to be hoisted up the mast of the shuttle’s payload bay.**

Per that Wikipedia link, of the four shuttle missions on which H flew (STS-75, STS-82, STS-101, STS-105) only STS-105 was in 2001.

**Question:** How did Scott Horowitz "hoist" the Mars Society's flag up STS-105's mast?

---

Side notes:

[Mars Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Society) and [logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mars_Society_logo.png), don't know what the flag looks like exactlyyet.

The "21st Century Transportation Network" references the [DAV Foundation... a blockchain-based open source global transportation company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAV_foundation):

> DAV Foundation has a decentralized transportation network, which enables different kinds of transportation companies to join the network. This network can work with autonomous vehicles, trucks, drones, cars, **and rovers.**

- [How would blockchain be integrated into spaceflight? Have any methods been proposed yet?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31207/12102)

Comment: I see a down vote, if there are any issues or concerns please let me know!

Comment: Not the downvoter! But wth is the "mast"? Not this unfortunately https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8229/6944 will look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @OrganicMarble ya I think that you've captured the essence of my question nicely, both "hoist" and "mast" come from the last sentence of the block quote. Do you think I should add quotes to mast as well in the title?

Comment: I've written several thousand SE question titles and I'm pretty comfortable with their results. I choose the words *carefully* so if there is an issue just let me know. Changing them around without asking or discussion can cause other issues that the changer-arounder may not have thought about, both in the title itself and in its relationship with the body of the question post.

Comment: In this case both "hoist" and "mast" appear in the last sentence of the block-quoted passage and their use is curious, and so I'm asking as much about them as about the "how" part. Thus they should remain in the title. As proposed above, I've gone ahead and added the quotes to the 2nd word to match the first.

Comment: I couldn't find anything, not even what the flag looks like.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks! Hmm... *curiouser and curiouser...*

Comment: @OrganicMarble https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Mars#:~:text=The%20sequence%20of%20colors%2C%20from,behalf%20of%20the%20Mars%20Society. it might be that design

Comment: @OrganicMarble despite the scare quoted terms in the title, do you think this question might be answerable?

Comment: The info is out there most likely, but I was never able to find anything. NASA burning down spaceflight.nasa.gov sure didn't help.